# Timeout::Error when using ActionMailer on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I'm trying to setup e-mail actions in my Rails app and I want to test the mailing functions locally. I followed [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) but sending mail throws a `Timeout::Error(execution expired)` error whenever I attempt to send mail.

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

**config/initializers/setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'recipes.dev',
  :user_name            => 'myemail@gmail.com',
  :password             => '*******',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

**mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

  def test_email(user)
    @email = user.email
    @name = user.name
    mail(:to => @email, :subject => 'test e-mail')
  end
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
UserMailer.test_email(@user).deliver
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your smpt_setting side development.rb as:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'recipes.dev',
  :user_name            => 'myemail@gmail.com',
  :password             => '*******',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

you don't need setup_mail.rb

please look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration